# Nativescript IOS icon change in background mode

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-vue

Hi Nativescript community,

When i swipe up close apps in iOS, the app icon is showing default icon.
How can i change this icon?

I used following commands to change my apps icons and splash screen icons and everything is fine in Android app and iOS app.

```
ns resources generate splashes ~/Desktop/icon.jpg --background "#FFFFFF"
ns resources generate icons ~/Desktop/icon.jpg
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think this is cache issue.
Try restarting device